# Pandas dataframe if case based on previous elements

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create the following "algorithm"

```
df['x'] = np.where(sum(df['x'][i-1],10)>0, 5, 10)
```

The idea here is that if the rolling sum of the last 10 elements, starting from the previous one, is positive then 5 else 10. I am looking for a data frame style solution without loops.

Comment: Can you add some data sample?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for `np.where(df['x'].rolling(10).sum()>=0,5,10)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df["previous"] = df.x.shift(1)
df["previous_rolling_sum"] = df.previous.rolling(2).sum()
df['x'] = np.where(df["previous_rolling_sum"]>0, 5, 10)
```